# Does ArgumentError lack backtrace_locations?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1

When I call `Exception#backtrace_locations`, it usually returns an array, as intended:

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue => e
  p e.backtrace_locations
end
# => ["this_file:2:in `<main>'"]
```

This is the same if I raise an `ArgumentError` manually:

```
begin
  raise ArgumentError.new
rescue => e
  p e.backtrace_locations
end
# => ["this_file:2:in `<main>'"]
```

However, when I raise a real `ArgumentError` by calling a method with wrong number of arguments, the `backtrace_locations` is `nil`, which is unexpected to me:

```
def foo; end

begin
  foo(:bar)
rescue => e
  p e.backtrace_locations
end
# => nil
```

Under the same situation, the classic `Exception#backtrace` returns an array, as intended:

```
def foo; end

begin
  foo(:bar)
rescue => e
  p e.backtrace
end
# => ["this_file:1:in `foo'", "this_file:4:in `<main>'"]
```

Is the return value of `Exception#backtrace_locations` being `nil` in the third case above intended? If so, when does `Exception#backtrace_locations` become `nil`? Is there any documentation for this? Or, is it a Ruby bug?

At this point, I think it is a bug, and [reported it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9295).

Comment: Looks like (if it's the same issue) it's not in 2.1 yet:  https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8960

Comment: @CDub What do you mean it's not in yet? Revision 44170 is supposed to have implemented it. And the method is returning `nil`; it is defined. If it is not defined, then it should rather raise an undefined error.

Comment: Per the last comment 12 days ago in the above thread:  "Target version changed from current: 2.1.0 to next minor" ... I read that as "it will be in the next minor release, it's not in 2.1.0."

Comment: Or maybe I found the wrong issue... I'm open to being wrong.  I've been wrong at least 131241 times today already. :)

Comment: @CDub Thanks for the comments. My interpretation of ko1's last comment on that thread is that he is done with `backtrace_locations`, but has not yet done `set_backtrace_locations` or the like. In that sense, it is half done, and has been set to the next minor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, and the maintainer ko1 just [fixed it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9295) in Revision 44411. Hopefully, it will make it into the release of Ruby 2.1 today.

**Edit** Turns out that it has not been fixed yet. Ruby 2.1 released today still has this issue.

**Edit** According to a maintainer, the fix will be incorporated into Ruby 2.1.1.